# How to destroy my subscriptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, destroy

I have a Product model, a User model and a Subcription model. A product has users trough subscriptions, a user has many products trough subscriptions and a subscription belongs to both.

When a user likes a product, it creates a new subscription for that. In my subscription_controller I've created the function `like_project` for that; works like a charm!

But I also tried to create a `unlike-project` function for destroying that specific subscription. I'm just not able to get it to work. I've already been told to destroy the relation instead of the object, but I already thought that the subscription was that relation.

So, how should I write my code to make sure that a user can also unlike it's liked products (or destroy the subscription)?

Here are my functions of my subscription-controller:

```
class SubscriptionController < ApplicationController

before_action :authenticate_user!
    def like_product
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    current_user.subscriptions.create(product: product)

    recommender = ProductRecommender.new
    recommender.add_to_matrix!(:users, "user-#{current_user.id}", "product-#{product.id}")

    redirect_to product     
end

def unlike_product
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
    product = @subscription.product
    @subscription.destroy

    recommender = ProductRecommender.new
    recommender.delete_from_matrix!(:users, "product-#{product.id}")

    redirect_to product     
end

private
    def subscription_params
        params.require(:subscription).permit(:product_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

This is how I like a product:

```
                <div class="card-action center">

                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <%= form_tag productsubscribe_path do %>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag 'product_id', @product.id %>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light black darken-2">Like project</button>
                    <% end %>
                <% else %>
                    <%= link_to new_user_session_path do %>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light black darken-2">Like project</button>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
                </div>
```

...and this is how I'm trying to unlike a product:

```
                <div class="">
                <%= form_tag productunsubscribe_path do %>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag 'product_id', @product.id %>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light black darken-2">Unlike product</button>
                <% end %>
                </div>
```

The recommender code that you can see is of a recommendation engine that add a set to a Redis matrix when a product is liked and deletes it when it's unliked. It doesn't cause any problems when liking a product and I'm assuming that it doesn't for unliking one as well ;)

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `unlike_product` controller method expects to use `params[:id]` to find the relevant subscription. However, in your form, it doesn't look like you pass in an `id` param at all - the only field you have is `product_id`:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'product_id', @product.id %>
```

What does `params[:id]` contain? Is it empty? How about `params[:product_id]`? We'd expect that not to be empty. And so rather than:

```
@subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
```

you'd instead be looking for the subscription where the product_id matches your param, and the user_id matches that of the logged in user.

Comment: Thanks @joshua. I think that I understand what you mean, but I'm not able to turn it into workable code. This is my first destroy ever and I'm starting to feel rather stupid ;)
I just tried the following, but it doesn't work:

  `@subscription = Subscription.where("product_id = :id AND user_id = #{current_user.id}")`

Comment: Try `@subscription = Subscription.where("product_id = #{params[:product_id]} AND user_id = #{current_user.id}")`

Comment: Or better yet, use placeholders: 

`Subscription.where("product_id = ? AND user_id = ?", params[: product_id], current_user.id)`

Comment: it returns a "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" for `@subscription.destroy`

Comment: Tried many things so far, but it still doesn't work. Nevertheless, I think that you've guided me into the proper direction, Thanks for that @joshua